# How to compare dates with django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a Post model which has vip membership end time. I want to count active memberships.

My model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name ='Başlık')
    image =  models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name ='Vitrin Fotoğrafı')
    vip = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name ='Vip')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11,verbose_name ='Telefon')
    vipend = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name ='Vip Bitiş')
```

My view:

```
def yonetim(request):

endvipcount = Post.objects.fiter(vip=True,vipend<datetime.now()).count() # This part is obviously wrong # 

context = {
    "endvipcount": endvipcount ,

    }
 return render(request, "yonetici.html", context)
```

Error:

```
endvipcount = Post.objects.fiter(vip=True, vipend < datetime.now()).count()
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want active and passive vip member counts. What is the ideal way of doing it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For SQL queries which use the `WHERE` clause you should use Django field look ups (see doc links)

You can use `__lt`:

```
Post.objects.fiter(vip=True, vipend__lt=datetime.now()).count()
```

Which means any Post objects where the vip field is true and the vipend field is less than `now()`.

You can also use `__date__lt` if you want to ignore the time component of the field.

[Django doc: lt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt)
[Django doc: date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date)

Comment: Actually the OP wants `__lt` (cf `vipend < datetime.now()`) xD

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, You are right, my bad. Edited.